# Will my warped(cupped) oak flooring flatten out after it dries?

Tags: water, flooring, finishing

I have a refrigerator sitting on a solid oak floor with a plywood underlay/subfloor that had the ice maker line break and the water got under the flooring and it is cupped now about 4 feet square on each side of the wall backing the fridge.

The floor is under the fridge on one side but on the other side of the wall (behind) it is in a hallway and is noticable.  I placed fans both at the floor from above and at the bottom/under the subflooring but did not note any improvement after several days.

Will the cupped floor settle over time as it dries out or will I have to remove and refinish?

Comment: It's not likely the warped wood will return to its former shape on its own.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you will probably have to replace that section.